# Creating new classifications

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, classification, nlp

Is it possible for an algorithm to predict a new class that has never been before in training? For example, in my training data I have:

`I need a flight to Boston --> flight query`

`What is two plus two --> math query`

`Who is the president of the United States --> Donald Trump`

How can I make a model that can predict a new class for:

```
How are you today --> ??? (Should be something like conversation query)
```

I am almost looking for a way to combine supervised learning and unsupervised learning. Using supervised learning for a model to predict new classes (unsupervised learning)

Comment: Do you plan on providing a set of possible classes?

Comment: This might be a [x y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you really interested in a generic open-ended classifier as your model (and if so, how are you expecting the computer to correctly label a new class, as opposed to simply identifying that it is a class it has not seen before and assign some kind of generic id), or are you trying to solve a different problem in NLP such as creating a [Topic Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a class label that the algorithm has never seen before? Then no, it is not possible. If you dont have labelled data for all your samples you can run a LDA, to get some topics and then assign labels based on the topics obtained. Even this approach wouldnt be really great. Since your problem is classification, I would recommend restricting your domain and using only samples for which the label is known. For better classification accuracy [you can look into CNN](http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/).

Comment: Yeah,  just suggested in case a BOW model doesn't work well. Have been working with them and found them useful so I suggested.

Comment: Did you mean to say "RNN"? I don't see how a CNN would replace bag-of-words.

Comment: I meant CNNs only. Check out Denny Britz's blog on text classification using CNNs. They work surprisingly well.

Comment: OK, thanks, I learned something new from that. I don't think it's been as well publicised as use of RNNs/LSTM. I've taken the liberty of editing in an explanatory link.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying *new* classes sounds like unsupervised learning to me, not supervised learning. Supervised learning implies a fixed set of labels (and appropriate training data) that you as a human provide, which is how you teach the machine.

Teaching the machine to identify new classes is a different matter altogether, you're essentially asking the machine to intelligently identify something it has no knowledge of, because no designated training data (=knowledge) exists in the model. This is, as far as I know, not possible.